# hyperbolic cosine in complex

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\frac {2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}$ always the same as $\frac {1}{\cosh x}$, because when I try to integrate those two expression from $R$ to $R+i\pi$, where $R$ is a positive real number, Wolfram Mathematica returns two different values. So what is the value of $\int_{R}^{R+i\pi}\frac{1}{\cosh x}$ ? I get $- 4\arctan[e^R]$, when I try to do the integral myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer can't be correct, because as $R \to \infty$, we must have $\left|\cosh (R + iy)\right| \to \infty$ for $y \in [0,\pi]$, so the limiting value of the integral should be $0$ as $R \to \infty$; but your result would imply it is $-2\pi$.  I also think that, due to the (anti)symmetry $$\cosh (i \pi - z) = -\cosh z,$$ that the integral should have zero real component and nonzero imaginary component.

---

```
Integrate[2/(Exp[R + I y] + Exp[-R - I y]), {y, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> R > 0]
```

yields the output $$-2i(\pi - 2 \tan^{-1} e^R).$$

```
Integrate[1/Cosh[x + I y], {y, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

yields $$-2i \tan^{-1} \coth \frac{x}{2} + i \operatorname{gd}(x),$$ which is equivalent for $x > 0$ but I haven't found a way to get *Mathematica* to transform the latter into the former.

Comment: ConditionalExpression[-4 ArcTan[E^R], E^(2 R) <= 1] is what Mathematica returns when integrating $\frac {2}{e^{x}+e^-{x}}$ and 2 (ArcTan[Coth[R/2]] - ArcTan[Tanh[R/2]]) when integrating $\frac {1}{cosh \space x}$... I realy dont know what I'm doing wrong with the integration per hand...

Comment: $\int_{R} ^{R+i \pi} \frac {2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}dx$ $=$ $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {2}{e^{R+ti}+e^{-R-ti}}i \space dt$ $->$ $h=e^{R+ti}$(new variable) $->$ $\int_{e^R}^{e^{R+\pi i}} \frac {2}{h^2+1}dh$ $=\arctan (e^{R+\pi i})-\arctan(e^R)$=$lim_{R->\infty}(\arctan (-e^{R})-\arctan(e^R))=-\pi$
What am I missing ?

Comment: Where the curve from $R$ to $R+i\pi$ is parameterized as $ \sigma = R+t i$